# securing datawarehouse by views

Tags: sql, view, data-warehouse

I'm trying to secure the datawarehouse by views.
Views already exist, but i want to integrate the filter on each view.
I tried to create a table which contains the clauses (select, where) of the view definition.

And I used a script to concatener the clauses of the view definition and the filter.

the problem is that the concatenation doesn't work because the query returns multiple lines.
I don't even know if it's a solution or i'm passing by.

This is what I’m trying:

```
SELECT  “select_clause_of_the_view” 
FROM “from_of_the view” left  join “filter_table”
WHERE “where_of_the_view”  + “where of the filter”
```

I'm working on IBM puredata for analytics

[image]

Comment: Please tag the proper RDBMS. I don't understand what you are trying to do. Add details and examples.

Comment: I don't understand it either. What do you think you will gain with those views?

Comment: i'm creating those views to limit access on some information

Comment: Please don't tag this Pure Data.

Comment: @S.AHEM Restricting access to certain information is usually done in the software that distributes your reports (or with which you build your reports). Handling this on DB level is just a pain in the ass.